# Search and replace multiple strings in a script using vim(search and replace) commands without sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed

A script that creates a file for weather precipitation is,

```
#!/bin/ksh

x=10
b=snow
c=rain
d=snow
e=hail
echo "$x,$b,$c,$d,$e" > weatherfile

exit 0
```

given

```
3,8s/snow/dry/g
```

For the search and replace, what is the best way to implement this in a script?

From the command perspective would `sed` be necessary?

My thoughts are that the following should work:

```
sed 3,8s/snow/dry/g weatherfile
```

Though what if `sed` could not be used. Would I need to open and close the file and some how run

`:3,8s/snow/dry/g` while the file is open? How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `vim` commands directly with a here-document (that is especially useful for irregular replacements):

```
#!/bin/ksh
vim weatherfile <<EOF
:3,8s/snow/dry/g
:wq
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it entirely in the shell with a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
line_num=0
while IFS= read -r line
do
        : $((line_num++))
        if [[ line_num -ge 3  &&  line_num -le 8 ]]
        then
                printf "%s\n" "${line/snow/dry}"
        else
                printf "%s\n" "$line"
        fi
done
```

<sub>(I've tested this in bash,
and [Andrey](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65213/andrey) reports
that it works in ksh,
but it won't work in all POSIX-compliant versions of `sh`.)</sub> 
It reads lines from the standard input. 
It counts lines (with `line_num=0` and `: $((line_num++))`
because you want to specify a line number range;
if that requirement is removed,
the statements referencing `line_num` can be deleted. 
The conditional test

```
        if [[ line_num -ge 3  &&  line_num -le 8 ]]
```

means “IF (line_num ≥ 3)  AND  (line_num ≤ 8)”,
corresponding to the range `3,8`, i.e., 3 through 8. 
(Which is a point of confusion for Unix newbies,
who expect `3,8` to mean “3 and also 8”,
and expect “3 through 8” to be represented as `3-8` —
i.e., the convention used by print dialog boxes in Windows
for printing a subset of the pages of a document.)

On the lines that are in the range, it uses the

```
        ${parameter/pattern/string)
```

form of parameter expansion to replace "snow" with "dry"
before writing the line out to the standard output. 
Lines outside the range are written unmodified.

This will change the first occurrence (if any) of "snow" on each line
within the range.  To replace all occurrences,
use `${line//snow/dry}` (insert an extra `/` before "snow").

I'm not clear on the big picture of what you want.

- You could incorporate the above code into your existing script.
- If you modified your script (let's call it `weather.sh`)
  to write to stdout rather than the file, then you could say

  ```
  ./weather.sh | ./do_substitute.sh > weatherfile
  ```
- If you want to create `weatherfile` the same way you are doing it now,
  but then change it afterwards, you could do

  ```
  ./do_substitute.sh < weatherfile > weatherfile.tmp
  mv weatherfile.tmp weatherfile
  ```

Comment: The script works in ksh (93u+ 2012-02-29).

Comment: @Andrey: Thanks for the information; I've edited it into my answer.

Comment: Makes sense, I seem to understand the usage of the loop. So, for each line the snow is left unmodified unless it meets the conditions you placed `[[ line_num -ge 3  &&  line_num -le 8 ]]`

Comment: Right; “(line_num ≥ 3) AND (line_num ≤ 8)” corresponds to the range `3,8`, i.e., 3 through 8.  (Which is a point of confusion for Unix newbies, who expect `3,8` to mean “3 and also 8”, and expect “3 through 8” to be represented as `3-8` — i.e., the convention used by print dialog boxes in Windows for printing a subset of the pages of a document.)